# Using lambda inside a function

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'm learning about lambda functions in Python through tutorials online. I understand how it works but I came across an example that puzzles me (on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)):

```
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)
print(mydoubler(11))
```

I don't understand how `mydoubler` function works here. How does it take 11 as an argument when we didn't define it before?

Comment: `mydoubler` is a reference to the lambda returned by `myfunc`, and takes an `a` as input. 11 is passed as this `a`.

Comment: `mydoubler` is `lambda a: a * n`, and so 11 is `a`, the only argument of that lambda.

Comment: you’re essentially making a curried function here

Answer (score 7):

`mydoubler` is what `myfunc(2)` returns. It returns a lambda that accepts a single argument, `a`.

When you call on a function like this: `myfunction(this_argument)`, it is going to resolve to what is returned in that spot. So this is effectively the same as writing `mydoubler = lambda a : a * 2`

Answer (score 4):

A `lambda` function is a small anonymous function. In your example

```
myfunc(2) # lambda a: a * 2
```

You translate it as apply a function on each input element. It is quite obvious when an input is just a scalar, for example

```
mydoubler(11) #outputs 11 * 2 = 22
```

But what do you expect when the input is an `array` or a `string`?

```
mydoubler([1,1,1]) #outputs [1,1,1] * 2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
mydoubler("str") #outputs "str" * 2 = "strstr"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example has two functions: the outer function `myfunc` and the inner function `lambda`. Normally you can call a `lambda` function directly:

```
n = 2
print((lambda a: a * n)(11))
# 22
```

Or you can assign some variable to this function and call it through this variable:

```
inner = lambda a: a * n
print(inner(11))
# 22
```

You can also define some outer function, which will return the inner `lambda` function:

```
def myfunc():
    n = 2
    return lambda a: a * n

mydoubler = myfunc()
print(mydoubler(11))
# 22
```

What is equivalent to:

```
mydoubler = lambda a: a * 2
print(mydoubler(11))
# 22
```

In the example above the variable `n` was declared inside `myfunc` and in your case `n` is the parameter of `myfunc`, which is passed to the `lambda` function. The function `myfunc` returns the`lambda` function with `n` equal to the argument, which you pass to `myfunc` by the function call. So the function call `myfunc(2)` returns the fuction `lambda a: a * 2`.

Answer (score 1):

as Python documentation says, lambda is only anonymous function

> Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create anonymous functions. The expression lambda parameters: expression yields a function object.

you can see it in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

what's going on in your snippet of code is that your `myfunc` function use `n` as a constant to new anonymous function that receive one parameter called `a` and return the multiplication of `a` with the `n`.
In your calling `n` value is `2`, result by your call `myfunc(2)`.
when you call `mydoubler(11)` you call your new anonymous function when `a` has value `11`

Answer (score 1):

- As per the lambda documentation in https://pythonreference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/lambda.html

  > lambda returns an anonymous function.
- In the above-mentioned example, lambda function is lambda a : a * n and
  the lambda itself returns some anonymous function which must be something like

  ```
  def mydoubler(a, n):
      return a*n
  ```
- But here, as we have already passed n=2 while calling myfun(), hence doing mydoubler(a) just returns a*2 (as here n=2) and hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here mydoubler=myfunc(2)
     #myfunc(2) returns  lambda function to mydoubler

```
 mydoubler=lambda a:a*2
 # it is similar to x=lambda a:a*2

 print(mydoubler(11)
 # it is similar to print(x(11))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you called the function after assigning mydoubler to it, it returned a function, the lambda FUNCTION, and, hence, mydoubler itself became a function and could be passed in parameters.

Comment: Hi @rajs welcome to stackoverflow. This is more of a comment than an answer. You should also take a look at the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

Had same question and landed here by google search. It seems hard at the beginning but crystal clear once understood.

myfunc defines a lambda function with parameter n which is unknown yet.

mydoubler defines a lambda function using myfunc with by giving value to that parameter n=2.

Keep in mind mydoubler is still a lambda function, so it takes variable(s) to work, here within the print function a=11.

Answer (score 0):

How do we write lambda func in simple 1 line i.e,
consider:

```
x = lambda a: a*3
print(x(2))
```

the output we expect is `2*3 =6`.

Here 2nd line `print(x(2))` is nothing but value of a to-be-considered if you write `print(x)` it will show error as `<function myfunc.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001F2D170AD40>` or something.

same thing in

```
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a : a * n
```

`mydoubler` is nothing but `(x) = myfunc(2)` is nothing but `(lambda a:a*2)` func, just name used are different.
`print(mydoubler(11))` is similar to `print(x(valueof a))`

Answer (score -2):

To understand this concept the above code can be simplified as given below:

```
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a : a*n
mydoubler = myfunc(2)
mydoubler(11)
```

This is only because lambda is itself a function . myfunc(2) is called and stored in mydoubler . Also myfunc(2) shares parameter i.e 2 with lambda. Lambda and mydoubler gets connected through myfunc(2). When mydoubler is called and passed with equal parameter to lambda,Lambda function will be automatically called.

Lambda function are the function which are defined without a name . There for it is also called anonymous function.

Comment: In this code, `myfunc` doesn't return anything and `mydoubler` is not defined.

Comment: on the same lines as @wjandrea, can you elaborate on the myfunc(2) or mydoubler(11) will illustrate these concepts?